# tinyMCE popup window root

Tags: iframe, popup, tinymce

on a web page I have an iFrame, inside which tinyMCE is loaded, nested structure looks like this:
**Window -> iFrame -> tinyMCE iframe**

In this case popup windows of tinyMCE are rooted in iFrame that holds tinyMCE.

Is there a way to make these popups appear rooted in main Window?

So what I have:
**Window -> iFrame [popup] -> tinyMCE iframe**

What I need:
**Window [popup] -> iFrame -> tinyMCE iframe**

Comment: are you using the tinymce init setting "inlinepopups: true," ?

Comment: yes, I am using inlinepopups, so new "windows" are created in an iframe.

Comment: inlienpopups means, you are NOT using an IFRAME for the popup

Comment: what I meant is that contents of inline popups is put in an iframe, but actually it's not the point. Does tinyMCE provide someway of putting the inline popups in a parent window element?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case don't add "`inlinepopups`" to your tinymce config parameter plugins!!!

Comment: But in this case popups will apear as separate windows. I want them to remain inline, but I want tiny to write it one level up of my iframe.

Comment: you are talking about which iframe? your own one or the editor iframe?

Comment: I've made a visual representation of what I need, please [see the pic here](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/1886/exampl.jpg)

Comment: ok, you could modify the dom after creation of the popup and append it to your desired location

Comment: Thanks for a tip, but it seems it's not that easy. If I append the popup window div to the body of upper level, the popup itself becomes unusable. Different plugins throw different errors, it seems that tinyMCE doesn't provide any way to do these manipulations..